# Accents in vim: Cannot write "â"

Tags: vim

I can't get "â" to be written. I can write "Â" though (carrot + capital A).

Any other accent can be written as in any other text editor.

Any suggestions?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: How are you inputting it?  See `:help digraphs` for more info, but you ought to be able to do `ctl-k a >`

Comment: Keyboard mappings and how they work depend on the operating system. You should mention the OS that you use, or add it to the tags.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You may want to look at the `:digraph` command in Vim.  It will show you the combinations to use with `<C-k>` to make accented characters.  In your case, you want `<C-k>` followed by `a>`.

Note: `<C-k>` means <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>k</kbd> whereas `a>` means the letter "a" followed by a ">" (greater than sign).

Answer (score 5):

If you are using a latin keyboard layout and are unable to directly type the accented character, check if there is any mapping using it:

> :verbose imap â

If so, just remap the command to another key.

Comment: This did it for me, and Auto-Pairs ended up being the culprit. https://github.com/jiangmiao/auto-pairs/issues/88

Answer (score 4):

`<C-K>a^` works for me in Vim 7.3.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `digraphs`, as pointed out on other answers. But this kind of diacritical character is very common on some languages. If that is true for you, you could set the `keymap` option:

```
:set keymap=accents
```

The list of characters added by this option can be seen in `$VIM\keymap\accents.vim`.

That being said, this should be working without this option. It is possible that you are with some problem with the value your `'enconding'` option, as [mentioned here](http://vim.1045645.n5.nabble.com/Diacritics-with-Vim-td1165398.html).

Answer (score 0):

First look at digraphs, as mentioned before.

But just to be thorough, and because I haven't seen it mentioned yet, note that any unicode character at all can be inserted via `<C-v>uXXXX<cr>` (where XXXX is the hexadecimal code point number of the character.)  More on this at `:help i_^v`

For a list of code point values for different characters, try:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters

Or use a handy Perl script called [unum](http://www.fourmilab.ch/webtools/unum/), which lets you search characters by name, and other fun stuff.

EDIT: markup fix